# How js select selector of part in href to make Previous and Next button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<li><a href="/chapter-1.html">Ch. 1 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a href="/chapter-2.html">Ch. 2 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a href="/chapter-3.html">Ch. 3 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a href="/chapter-4.html">Ch. 4 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a href="/chapter-5.html">Ch. 5 - TitleHere</a></li>
```

These are several links to my static pages on my website. They have numbers on the end of their href.

Now, I want to make the next and previous buttons (by plus/minus the number inside the href by 1). But I was confused to make a selector to that number inside the href.

But, let it be an alert function for now.

```
<button type="button" onclick="getURL();">Get Page URL</button>
    
    <script>
      var current = window.location.pathname;
        function getURL() {
        alert(current + 1);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use data-attributes in your li or a tags.

Comment: add `data-page="1"` to your HTML for a tag page 1, then in JS, function getURL() => `alert(current + a.dataset.page);`, ***`a`*** being a defined variable within an each loop for your list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right lines getting the current url as you are doing.

Once you have that string you can split it at the chapter- string. That will give you an array which has two strings. The first item has the full url up to and including the / character before the chapter- and the second item has the number followed by the .html. So you can find the number by removing the .html from that item.

To create the URL when the user clicks the Next button get the number and if it is less than 5 add 1 to it then make the (relative) URL you want to go to by putting together the chapter- + the new n + .html. Then do a window location to this URL.

The Previous button is much the same except the test is that the number is greater than 1 and subtract 1 from it.

```
<button type="button" onclick="previous();">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="next();">Next</button>
    
    <script>
      const current = window.location.pathname;
      const twoParts = current.split('chapter-');
      var number = twoParts[1].replace('.html', '');
      function next() {
        if (number < 5) { alert(number); gotoChapter(++number); };
      }
      function previous() {
        if (number > 1) { gotoChapter(--number); }
      }
      function gotoChapter(n) {
          window.location = 'chapter-' + n + '.html';
      }
    </script>
```

You could create the previous and next buttons using JS too and so not create Next if number is 5 nor create Previous is number is 0.

Comment: I think this one work for me. The syntax 'current.split' opens my mind clearly. Thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ***dataset*** attribute for this, just add each page to your HTML as a ***dataset***, then reference the ***dataset*** in your JS to get the *page* for the ***event*** being *clicked*, then append to your `current` variable with the `a` tags ***dataset*** value that is being clicked.

```js
const $li = $('li a')
$li.each(function(index, a){
  const current = window.location.pathname;
  function getURL(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(current + a.dataset.page);   
  }  
  a.addEventListener('click', getURL);  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a data-page="1" href="/chapter-1.html">Ch. 1 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a data-page="2" href="/chapter-2.html">Ch. 2 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a data-page="3" href="/chapter-3.html">Ch. 3 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a data-page="4" href="/chapter-4.html">Ch. 4 - TitleHere</a></li>
<li><a data-page="5" href="/chapter-5.html">Ch. 5 - TitleHere</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done using page ids approach, on server side but this can also be done by using your approach:

```
<button onclick="getURL()" ></button>
<script>
//get the page number from "/chapter-ThisIsYourPageNumber.html" , its between "-" and "."
var current = window.location.pathname;
var start = current.indexOf("-") + 1; //+1 get start index of page number
var end = current.indexOf(".");
var length = end - start;
var pageNumber = current.substr(start, length);
var nextPageNumber = parseInt(pageNumber) + 1;
function getURL() {
    alert("/chapter-"+nextPageNumber+".html");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think it won't work if the URL has more than one "-" on its pathname. can I specify the ("-") on the start variable to another syntax, maybe specify it to ("chapter-")?

Comment: You are right @OntaKutub , this code will work when the static pages name follows the current chapter naming pattern. i.e. chapter-PageNumber.html